# Window capture with embeded (setparent) directx game C#

Tags: c#, directx, screenshot

Goal:
- Capture a winform window containing a directx game window (like screenshot, but specific handle).

Scenario:
- Inside a winform I insert a panel1 normally.
- I used the winapi SETPARENT to insert a directx main game window inside the penel1

Problem:
When capturing the winform window (this.handle), the image of the embedded game in the panel1 does not appear. Only the panel appears.
I can't use the ScreenShot method, because it will get another window over.

Example:
[image: With screenshot. capturing the screen]
[image: With WinAPI. capturing the specific window]

```
public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle, int imgX = 0, int imgY = 0, int largura = 0, int altura = 0)            
    {
        // get te hDC of the target window
        IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);            
        // get the size
        User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
        User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
        if(largura == 0 || altura == 0)
        {
            largura = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            altura = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
        }
        // create a device context we can copy to
        IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
        // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
        // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
        IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, largura, altura);            
        // select the bitmap object
        IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
        // bitblt over            
        //GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, largura, altura, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
        GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, largura, altura, hdcSrc, imgX, imgY, GDI32.SRCCOPY);            
        // restore selection
        GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);            
        // clean up 
        GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);
        // get a .NET image object for it
        Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);            
        // free up the Bitmap object
        GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

       return img;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After use SetParent with Directx window, need to refresh the winform.
Just: this.Refresh();